# View_State Correlation in Loadrunner 11.5

Tags: testing, loadrunner, automated-tests

I am working on Loadrunner to record an automated script for testing a search based asp/ajax web page. On a button click following url is generated:

```
http://test-adept2/adept/accountmain.aspx?ap=vGU2A5TaN7E%3d&ied=64k1tL5TuqHN7rddKI4lKw%3d%3d&mk8=xqE4vIisjxQ%3d&plang=U7YPQ8m0mhU%3d&vo=lfEpsuQV%2bcg%3d
```

I figured **ied=64k1tL5TuqHN7rddKI4lKw%3d%3d** is the dynamic value that is to be correlated. However I coudn't find this value in previous response. I am kind of new to correlation, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

After the inspection, I got the following code:

[image]

I explored the click event listener and found the following code, I am still not sure what part of this script is generating the above mentioned unique ID (ied)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I manage to solve the issue and I appreciate the answers. The issue basically was that I was using wrong protocol in this case, I was using web HTML/HTTP while there was a lot of AJAX/ASP involved. Hence the LoadRunner was not able to capture most of the Javascirpt functions. I recorded the script using Web Click/Script protocol and the flow worked like a charm. In this protocol I didn't have to bother about correlation as well. Only tricky thing was the parameterization part while replaying the script.

Comment: Glad you worked it out.  Finding the javascript code is a little tricky, you have to div deep into the include.postload.js in your case.  Unless you need to do high capacity testing, you don't have to worry about all these ugly details since the web click/script takes care of them.

Answer (score 1):

> I am kind of new to correlation

This is the topic of 1/3 of the standard HP training: You need training.  You need to be assigned a mentor.   If your management has not taken these minimum steps to ensure your success then they are more interested in things other than success

Here is a tool agnostic view of how to find correlation candidates, but this in no way will replace a need for training and a mentor.  Correlation is a principal mechanical skill for a performance tester, independent of tool.

http://www.perfbytes.com/dynamic-data-correlation

Answer (score 1):

If "64k1tL5TuqHN7rddKI4lKw%3d%3d" is not in the previous response, most likely it's constructed by some javascript. If you could locate the javascript snippet that got triggered when you clicked on the button, then you can study and implement it on your own - when you can do that, you turn yourself into a top performance tester :-)

If you use Google Chrome browser, you can go to developer tool page by right clicking the button and select the menu "Inspect Element" in the popup menu. Then in the developer console, locate the right pane and find "Event Listeners", you may be able to find the javascript code that get triggered there.  [image: locate "Event Listeners"]

I have seen web page where the javascript does a base64 operation on some hidden fields in a HTTP form. In that case, it's fairly easy to implement and generate the HTTP request.

HP TruClient can take care of this automatically, but it may have lower capacity than your need.

If you could send me the page you are testing, I can take a look at it too.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip.I updated the question with inspected element. Kindly have a look.